# Bitbucket tag automatic rollback

Tags: git, bitbucket, devops, tagging

I'm adding few files to an existing  tag in particular branch in bitbucket.
At that time those few files were tagged with required tag I'd, but after sometime tag was moved/rolled back automatically to old commitid (one last latest) .
May I get a solution for this automatic rollback

I want the added files to be in the assigned tag .

Comment: Tags mark a specific commit at a point in your repository history. You can not add files to a existing tag. You might want to delete that tag, and put it on your latest commit.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start "adding files to a tag", what you actually need is to create a branch, representing the latest state, starting from that tag.

```
git switch -c newBranch myTag
git add .
git commit -m "Add files to evolve myTag state"
git push -u origin newBranch
```

That means `newBranch` will track evolution done from the codebase as it was starting at myTag, even if that tag start being rollback.

Comment: Actually we adding new files  to the existing tag by doing force tag  option

Comment: @AnbalaganM You do not force a tag: a tag is immutable, or it is no longer a tag. A branch HEAD is what you want: it will move on each commit.

Comment: Just now we found a issue that after adding a new file to an existing tag and build has been taken from jenkins, this rollback happening automatically, kindly someone suggest on this

Comment: @AnbalaganM My suggestion: create a branch from the tag: using that branch, you can add all the files you need.